# Analyzer warns that an argument type can't be itself

Tags: dart

The error: The argument type 'AdvformBaseComponent(advform/base.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AdvformBaseComponent(advform/base.dart)'.

The analyzer is warning that the argument type can't be AdvformBaseComponent, but the function is expecting that exact class as argument:

```
void addControl(AdvformBaseComponent baseComponent, String fieldName);
```

the below snippet is within a ngOnInit of AdvformBaseComponent.

```
objector.addControl(this, name);
```

It only hides the warning if I do a "addControl(this as dynamic", but that is so hacky and non performant...
sdk 1.22.1

[image: the weird warning]

EDIT:

The AdvformBaseComponent is an abstract class that is implemented by other components. It is essentially a base class for form components.
The AdvformObjectComponent is a panel group of AdvformBaseComponent based components. It is mandatory that any AdvformBaseComponent have a parent of AdvformObjectComponent.
They are in the same project and same directory.
I can share these files if you find it useful, they are browser components anyway.

```
abstract class AdvformBaseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit,
        OnDestroy {
    AdvformObjectComponent objector;
    AdvformBaseComponent(this.objector, @Optional() this._submitter, this.translator, @Optional() this._group) {
        if (objector == null)
            throw new Exception(
                    'Advform inputs must have a advform-object as parent.');
    }
}




class AdvformObjectComponent implements OnInit {
  void addControl(AdvformBaseComponent baseComponent, String fieldName) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `objector`. Can you please provide more code?

Comment: This can't work. How would you create an `AdvformBaseComponent` (or subclass) if you first need an instance to be able to create one because it's required as a constructor parameter. How do you provide `AdvformObjectComponent`?

Comment: It is currently working, the problem is just the analyzer. I need the objector within the base component because the objector is a parent node within the html. it is only a panel basically. I can't see the complexity here =\

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on from the few lines of code you posted.

Comment: I do not get any strong errors for the code snippet you provided: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/804d51ad9a85c0f60ec8bec6c252b5b3

Comment: Hi, just uploaded the zip with the project: http://vai.la/rzxv

Comment: What version of the Dart SDK are you using?
I'm on 1.23.0-dev.9.0 and I see no issues in analyzer

Comment: Dart SDK 1.22.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error stopped after the 1.23.0